# Несколько вопросов по Entity Framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, entity-framework, веб-программирование

1)У меня на колонке с типом DateTime стоит Default GetDate()и Not Null
Когда я добавляю новое значения без явного указания времени, то вылетает ошибка:"Не получилось сконвертировать DateTime2 в DateTime".
Если явно присваивать `DateTime.Now` , то все хорошо.

Классы я генерил на основании уже созданной базы. 
Есть ли решение данной проблемы?

2) Правильно ли порождать в методах дополнительные контексты или лучше их передавать через параметр?

Comment: Задавайте по 1 вопросу в вопросе

Comment: Откуда берется DateTime2?

Answer (score 1):

- 1.

  На первый вопрос уже есть ответ на англоязычном разделе:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298616/the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-error
- 2.
  Почитайте про паттерны repository и UnitOfWork.